# How can I automatically run all the functions in the module?

Tags: python

I need to run several functions in a module as follws:

```
mylist = open('filing2.txt').read()
noTables = remove_tables(mylist)
newPassage = clean_text_passage(noTables)
replacement = replace(newPassage)
ncount = count_words(replacement)
riskcount = risk_count(ncount)
```

Is there any way that I can run all the functions at once? Should I make all the functions into a big function and run that big function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach.

You could write a general function somewhat like that shown in the [**First-class composition**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29#First-class_composition) section of the Wikipedia article on *Function composition*. Note that unlike in the article the functions are applied in the the order they are listed in the call to `compose()`.

```
try:
    from functools import reduce  # Python 3 compatibility
except:
    pass

def compose(*funcs, **kwargs):
    """Compose a series of functions (...(f3(f2(f1(*args, **kwargs))))) into
    a single composite function which passes the result of each
    function as the argument to the next, from the first to last
    given.
    """
    return reduce(lambda f, g:
                    lambda *args, **kwargs: f(g(*args, **kwargs)),
                        reversed(funcs))
```

Here's a trivial example illustrating what it does:

```
f = lambda x: 'f({!r})'.format(x)
g = lambda x: 'g({})'.format(x)
h = lambda x: 'h({})'.format(x)

my_composition = compose(f, g, h)
print my_composition('X')
```

Output:

```
h(g(f('X')))
```

Here's how it could be applied to the series of functions in your module:

```
my_composition = compose(remove_tables, clean_text_passage, replace,
                         count_words, risk_count)
with open('filing2.txt') as input:
    riskcount = my_composition(input.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make a new function in the module which executes the common sequence being used. This will require you to figure out what input arguments are required and what results to return. So given the code you posted, the new function might look something like this -- I just guessed as to what final results you might be interested in. Also note that I opened the file within a `with` statement to ensure that it gets closed after reading it.

```
def do_combination(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as input:
        mylist = input.read()
    noTables = remove_tables(mylist)
    newPassage = clean_text_passage(noTables)
    replacement = replace(newPassage)
    ncount = count_words(replacement)
    riskcount = risk_count(ncount)

    return replacement, riskcount
```

Example of usage:

```
replacement, riskcount = do_combination('filing2.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply store these lines in a Python (.py) file you can simply execute them.

Or am I missing something here?

Creating a function is also easy to call them though:

```
def main():
    mylist = open('filing2.txt').read()
    noTables = remove_tables(mylist)
    newPassage = clean_text_passage(noTables)
    replacement = replace(newPassage)
    ncount = count_words(replacement)
    riskcount = risk_count(ncount)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, use need function composition. There is no special function for this in Python stdlib, but you can do this with `reduce` function:

```
funcs = [remove_tables, clean_text_passage, replace, count_words, risk_count]
do_all = lambda args: reduce(lambda prev, f: f(prev), funcs, args)
```

Using as

```
with open('filing2.txt') as f:
    riskcount = do_all(f.read())
```

Comment: +1 for `with`, -2 for suggesting `reduce` chaining for this, +1 for good intentions == 0.  Chaining like this is slightly more concise in this very particular case, but isn't robust at all.

Comment: +1: I don't think it's significantly less robust that the original code. Might also make the `funcs` list an argument to `do_all()` as well.

Comment: @martineau If we add `funcs` as param, we will get `composition` is general case :)

Comment: @AlexeyKachayev: right now, he's hardcoded the word "risk" into his `risk_count` function.  Let's say he decided to make that a parameter.  Please modify your code to handle this case, so that we can compare it against the standard solution; I can't see how to do it without yet another lambda or partial.  Might as well add an `if` branch, while you're at it.

Comment: @DSM I proposed solution for concrete question, not for all "possible changes with code in future".

Comment: Maybe this is a language issue?  By robust, I mean something like "still works under perturbations".  If you agree that as soon as the code changes, your approach doesn't work too well, then it seems we both agree that your approach isn't robust.